# in this part of my code i have tried to ask the user and im using if else statements to validate it

Tags: python

```
import operator
import csv
question= input("Are you a student or teacher: ")
if question=="student" or "s" or "Student":
    print("You are using the wrong program. Please use the arithmetic quiz")
elif question=="teacher" or "t" or "Teacher":
    print("Hello and welcome to the program which lets you see your students' scores in the arithmetic quizes")
```

In this code I have tried to use `if else` statements, but it doesnt work.

I have already tried several ways to make it work but it doesnt.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the input is in a tuple:

```
question= input("Are you a student or teacher: ")
if question in ("student", "s", "Student"):
    print("You are using the wrong program. Please use the arithmetic quiz")
elif question in ("teacher", "t", "Teacher"):
    print("Hello and welcome to the program which lets you see your students' scores in the arithmetic quizes")
```

Comment: i dont understand what a tuple is

Comment: @bob a tuple is a unmutable list

Comment: also what you told me to do doesnt work either

Comment: yes it does, in python 3.x in python 2.7 change input to raw_input